WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error when sending transaction
I am creating a staking transaction in my backend, and I want to consume it in the frontend. I have previously created others (withdraw, claim, unstake), and they work correctly.
However, I am unable to make the staking transaction work. The transaction is generated correctly, and I have even tested it on the Solana explorer, where it works properly (see image) this is the url: Transaction Inspector.

However, when I try to send and confirm it, I receive the following error, right after clicking confirm in phantom:

I have reviewed every part of the transaction and changed the Wallet Adapter, but I am still receiving the same error. Do you have any ideas about what might be happening and how to fix it?
Thank you very much in advance.

could you skipPreflight and share the tx link from the explorer.

@Jimii I do have it set in the options of sendTransaction. Even with that, the transaction is not being sent so I do not have any Tx

yes. Even if it fails, it should still submit your transaction to the network where everyone can see.

Hi. Thanks for helping. I finally made it. The error was that the payer of the instructions was another wallet which is missed out configuring. It works now.
Have a good day!

Awesome. Could you post this as the answer and mark it as that.


I finally made it. The error was that the payer of the instructions was another wallet which is missed out configuring. It works now.

